# with showcqt filter, which letter stands for which frequency?

Tags: ffmpeg

Why some letters are blue, while the rest is red?

[image: cqt example]

Comment: -10 

hide help
12 more to go...

Comment: "EF G" are blue here. Everything else is red.

Comment: A4 = 440 Hz, but there are so many A. Which one is 4? The 4th from the left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very first A is A0. So A4 is the one highlighted in the image below:

[image: ffmpeg showcqt filter - A4 440Hz tone]

View it via `ffplay -f lavfi -i sine=f=440,showcqt=s=640x360`